# Pass Path Parameter to a Exe File in a batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to pass the path parameter to the exe file:

```
TableUpdate.exe "C:\Documents"
```

In my batch File i written as :

```
@set Fpath = "C:\Documents"
@TableUpdate.exe %Fpath%
```

but when i enter the the path directly that exe file is able to recognize the execute but when i pass the path as parameter but it is not able to recognize the path passed. How to pass the path as parameter to exe file in a batch file.

Comment: Its not working with @call...

Answer (score 1):

```
set Fpath = "C:\Documents"
```

Remove the spaces on both sides of the equals sign as they are included in the variable name and the variable contents.

This is one way to specify it.

```
set Fpath="C:\Documents"
```

The `@` is ok, but not needed when you have `@echo off` at the start.